# Is there easier way to fill this holes?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

[image]

Hello, I want to fill the holes in left cube like to right cube.
(Like leaving window holes in some walls and the walls have already modeled)

I've done this with select each edges and press F to fill hole.
This is too much of a hassle if this model has so many edges or so big.

Any other easier way to fill these holes?
Or should i re-make this with other proper way?

Comment: Select the two inner "rings", right click and select "bridge edge loops".

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly too,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with LoopTools add-on. You can enable it under: Edit > Preferences > add-ons (search for LoopTools).

Then toggle X-Ray with Alt+Z or clicking in the icon, select all the vertex and right click > LoopTools > Bridge.

[image]

Comment: Oh God, Thank you so much :D XD ;D

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in function for this called **Bridge Edge Loops**.

While in the 3D Viewport, you can select it from the menu: **Edge → Bridge Edge Loops**

[image]

Your edge count should match on both edge loops you want to bridge, otherwise you'll end up with tris instead of quads. (Bridge Edge Loops didn't use to support mis-matched edge counts, but now it seems it will at least try to fill it for you anyway... or at least *"tri"?* Sorry...)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

1. With the F2 addon enabled, select two opposite vertices.
2. Press <kbd>F</kbd>, this creates an edge between those vertices.
3. Keep clicking <kbd>F</kbd> several times until the whole loop is closed with faces.

[image: F2 addon]